# Looking for an entityreference widget that allows to preselect an entity bundle

Tags: entities

I'm using one entityreference field in many entity types (bundles) because of the convenience that gives in Panels (just one relation to add in context).

However, the drawback is that the standard entityreference widgets show one bunch of target entities, which is not userfriendly.

What I want is a widget that includes a select field for the entity type (bundle) in order to filter the select field next to it.

I saw the [Entityreference View Widget](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_view_widget) but but I'm looking for something more simple, just two select fields of which the first filters the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This module does it: Entity Reference Dynamic Select 
https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_dynamicselect_widget